# Access denied to file

Tags: c#, file

So... I'am working on project, and I need to read an `.ini` file. But when I try to access the file with `File.ReadAllText` or `StreamReader` it throws an exception (`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`). I've checked and file is not readonly, and even if it was it wouldn't matter. Right? Also I've set permission to file for `ALL` to `allow all`. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: what about containing folders? the file may be "all", but the app still needs to be allowed access to all the directories leading up to the file.

Comment: I've checked and file is not readonly, and even if it was it wouldn't matter. Right? No thats not right, anyway could you please provide some code or show us at least where you keep your file?

Comment: have you tried copying the file to your local.. if it works locally then you know that it's a permissions issue trying to read/access it remotely

Comment: File is located in... well... in place where application is located. And actual location of application is in my visual studio build folder.

Comment: then you need to check and make sure you have all the permissions set properly ..

Comment: @CryoErger DJ is right, maybe your account doesn't have permissions, try switching to the administrator

Comment: I'am currently logged as administrator.

Comment: read this one through, especially M00NST0RM's answer. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1988cec-b74c-4375-9b1b-6929a8a724dd/how-to-avoid-systemunauthorizedaccessexception.

Comment: OK... but I'am able to list directories and files in that folder (using .NET). And in case that M00NST0RM describes, I wouldn't be able to do that.